# Linq Result into Observable collection throws parsing exception

Tags: c#, linq

I have created an observable collection

```
 public ObservableCollection<DatagGridCollection> combine_audit_final_collection { get; set; }
```

which I'm trying to populate via linq result

```
  var d =  (from p in Auditcollectiondata
                           from c in Finalcollectiondata
                           where c.sno == p.sno
                           select new
                            {
                                p.sno,
                                p.AuditID,
                                p.claimnumber,
                                p.QueryID,
                                p.DateWorked,
                                p.UserID,
                                p.Line,
                                p.Dos,
                                p.CPT,
                                p.Units,
                                p.amtBilled,
                                p.RecoupUnit,
                                p.reocupamts,
                                p.ScioNote,
                                p.Linelevelstatus_valuetext,
                                p.providerNote,
                                c.ID_finalstatus,
                                c.FinalStatus
                     });
```

The join works fine but when I try to insert the results into observable collection. I'm getting casting error.

```
    combine_audit_final_collection = new ObservableCollection<DatagGridCollection>((ObservableCollection<DatagGridCollection>) d);
```

The `combine_audit_final_collection` will be binded into the datagrid. Though there is no compile error I'm getting parsing exception at runtime while execute.

Update : I try to join two observable collection using sno and inserting the result into another observable collection 'combine_audit_final_collection'. If my approach is wrong please let me know any other approach.

```
public class DatagGridCollection
{
   public bool update { get; set; }
   public int sno { get; set; }
   public string AuditID { get; set; }
   public string claimnumber { get; set; }
   public string QueryID { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateWorked { get; set; }
   public string UserID { get; set; }
   public string Line { get; set; }
   public string Dos { get; set; }
   public string CPT { get; set; }
   public string Units { get; set; }
   public string amtBilled { get; set; }
   public string RecoupUnit { get; set; }
   public string reocupamts { get; set; }
   public string ScioNote { get; set; }
   public string Linelevelstatus_valuetext { get; set; }
   public string providerNote { get; set; }
   public int final_status_sno { get; set; }
   public string Finalstatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what exact error you are getting? `d` is a collection of anonymous types, I think that can not be converted to `ObservableCollection<DatagGridCollection>`

Comment: yes as you said I tried most of the solution but I get the error like anonymous type can't be converted into observable collection. The error I'm getting is xamlparserexception this exception occurs when I try to assign value to combine_audit_final_collection. If there is any workaround to my approach let me know.

Comment: You might want to use some other class then DataGridCollection class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your ObservableCollection is a collection of `DataGridCollections`? Is every element of your collection a `DataGridCollection`?

If not, but it is in fact a collection of `MyType`, change the word `DataGridCollection` below with `MyType`

Anyway, if you would check in your debugger the type of object `d`, you would notice that it is not an `IEnumerable<DatagGridCollection>`.

Just change your code to:

```
select new DataGridCollection()
{
   p.sno,
   ...
```

If you want to detect the cause of this kind of errors in the future, my advice would be not to use the word var too much, and not to do too much statements at once.

```
IEnumerable<DataGridCollection> d = ...
    Select new DataGridCollection
    {
        ...
    };

combine_audit_final_collection = new ObservableCollection<DatagGridCollection>(d);
```

It will be much easier to find your errors.